# How do I sort these values while retaining initial index?

Tags: java, c++, c, arrays, sorting

I want to seat a group of 4 people in a theater, so that they sit together in a row or have the most people next to each other. I have an array of rows where the index represents the row which stores how many available seats are in that row. If I used the sort method then it will sort the available seats but I will lose which row it corresponds to. Obviously I can loop through it looking for the max amount of seat I want and if I don't find that, I can decrement my amount and so on but that is not optimal.

Row: 1 2 3 4

Available: 2 3 1 4

Sorted Available: 4 3 2 1

Corresponding Row: 4 2 1 3 <- this is what I want

```
//this is one way to do it but i want a better way
int[] row = {0, 2, 3, 1, 4};
double[] rowDouble = new double[row.length];

for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
{
    String rowString = Integer.toString(row[i]) + "." + Integer.toString(i);
    rowDouble[i] = Double.valueOf(rowString);
}

Arrays.sort(rowDouble);
String sortedRowString = Arrays.toString(rowDouble);
sortedRowString = sortedRowString.substring(1, sortedRowString.length()-1);

System.out.println(sortedRowString);
String[] finalSortedRowString = sortedRowString.split(", ");

for (int i = finalSortedRowString.length-1; i > 0; i--)
{
    System.out.println(finalSortedRowString[i].split("\\.")[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? How do you get your corresponding row answer?

Comment: Are there only 4 people to be seated? Inputs - Row, Available and Sorted Available - do not make sense in the context of having 4 people. Not to me anyway.

Comment: Rows hold available values. So when I call 1 from row like row[1] I get 2. I need to know which row has the most available values. So I need to sort available values but keep track of what row it corresponds to.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're coming at this with the wrong paradigm.  Java is an Object oriented language, and you should be using it as such.

```
public Class Row {
    private int available;
    private int rownum;
    public Row(int avail, int rown) { /*...*/ }
    public int compareTo(Row otherRow) { /*...*/ }
    public int checkAvailable() { /*...*/ }
    public int addPerson() { /*...*/ }
    public int addSeat() { /*...*/ }
    public int addParty(int size) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Then you can use one of the many Java collections available to hold and sort them however you like.  It's some extra coding, but it will allow for more robust and extensible implementations.  For instance:  what if your row has two seats available, but they're on either end? Your current implementation would have to be scrubbed entirely.  Here, you'd just have to change the logic in a couple places, and BAM, you've got v2.

Please, strongly consider using the language to your advantage.  Don't use java as a scripting language, that's not what it's for.

Comment: I have that in my real program ie a separate method for individual and group seats. I hold my rows in an ArrayList of ArrayLists holding row# and seat objects. So I need to get my seat object sizes in descending order.